Laravel Horizon supervisor usages 80-90% CPU
is there any better process controller insted of supervisor ? supervisor is too much resource hungry, it consumes 80-90 % CPU when mysql process runs in multiple worker. By using cron my pending jobs are like 7-8k and takes more than 20 minuites to attempt job.
How to configure horizon & supervisor for better performance
i want to run horizon & supervisor to handle laravel queue jobs

Supervisord is not CPU hungry, it must be a process from inside it, like Horizon, as you are running 7-8k jobs...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
